# Transparent Swing Windows

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a little `JWindow` with a logo on it that users can drag stuff to.
I develop my application mainly on OS X. To get a transparent window i use

```
setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
```

On a mac this works beautifully but I can't get the same effect on windows.
Is there any way to get a transparent window without using 1.6 specific features.

I need 1.5 compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 1.5 Java does not support transparent windows.
This feature is introduced as part of 1.6.10 release.
See AWTUtilities class for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, windows (previous to Vista at least) doesn't do this kind of compositing. There is however a workaround. Example code can be found at http://rabbit-hole.blogspot.com/2007/02/non-rectangular-windows-update.html

Comment: JNA (http://github.com/twall/jna) provides this functionality in a utility class.